# How to transpile specific package in node_modules using craco

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, craco

I have a React app created using create-react-app. I want to use esnext version of vis-timeline library. [As docs says](https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline?tab=readme-ov-file#esnext-build), this version is untranspiled and I need to transpile it manually.

The following is my craco config.

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    configure(webpackConfig) {
      webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
          /node_modules\/vis-timeline\/esnext/,
        ],
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining"],
          },
        },
      });

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

When I run development server with `craco start` command, I receive this error:

[image]

And a lot of errors in the browser console:

[image]

It looks like I broke the transpilation process completely. How can I transpile a specific node_modules from craco.config.js?

Package versions:

- "@craco/craco": "^6.2.0"
- "typescript": "^4.1.2"
- "react": "^17.0.2".